# ListView data repeating

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

Data from parsed XML is fed into an ArrayList itemList. Results meeting the criteria are then added to filteredList, which in turn is bound to the adapter to be displayed in my ListView. However, the data being added to filteredList is being repeated (twice) and I do not understand why. Could anyone perhaps point it out for me? I've been staring at it for a while now lol.

Here is the function from MainActivity.java

```
private void FilterList() {

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.info);    //locate listview

        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) //cycle arraylist
        {
            try {
                //convert startdate, endDate
                Date cDate = dateFormat.parse(currDate);     //get/convert selected date
                Date stDate = dateFormat.parse(itemList.get(i).startDate);
                Date enDate = dateFormat.parse(itemList.get(i).endDate);
                //compare, if active true then add
                if ((cDate.after(stDate)) && (cDate.before(enDate))){
                    //add itemList element to filterList
                    filteredList.add(itemList.get(i));
                    Log.d("DEBUG CHECKME", "added to filteredList: ");
                }
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        itemAdapter = new PostItemAdapter(mcontext, R.layout.postitem, filteredList);   //pass results into adapter
        lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter); //bind listview & adapter
            Log.d("DEBUG CHECKME", "lv.setAdapter");
    }
```

And here is my adapter class:

```
public class PostItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Item> datas;

    public PostItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        datas = objects;
    }

    //class to hold view object references
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView itemTitleView;
        ImageView itemThumbView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.itemThumbView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemThumb);
            viewHolder.itemTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleLabel);
            //viewHolder.itemDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDateLabel);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (datas.get(position).itemThumbUrl == null)
        {
            viewHolder.itemThumbView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
        }

        viewHolder.itemTitleView.setText(datas.get(position).itemTitle);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: log the size of list before binding it to the adapter.

Comment: 1. Check how many time you call `FilterList` function.
2. Try to clear `filteredList` before add new result.

Comment: your adapter code is fine. I would use a debugger to check why your items are added to the list twice.

Comment: I would recommend to add a debug statement to 'FilterList()' and check how many times is being call.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is indeed being called twice (must be my hacky date picker in which it sits).

Comment: Are you checking anywhere if the data is already been added

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it will help you

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, parent, false);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }
             filteredList datas= rowItems.get(position);
            try {
                TextView itemTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleLabel);
               itemTitleView.setText(datas.itemTitle);


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            try {
            ImageView     itemThumbView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemThumb);
    itemThumbView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }




            });

            return row;
        }
```